# How to use different PostgreSQL instace for testing from production

Tags: postgresql, docker

I need my docker containers to connect to different PostgreSQL server, depending on the environment (test & production). What I desire is testing my application locally with local database instance, and push the fixes after. From what I read, PostgreSQL's default connection parameters can be determined by [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html), so I think writing two different environment variables files for test/production and pass the desired one in with `--env-file` option of `docker run` command would do the trick.

Is this a suitable way to test & deploy an web application? If not, what would be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general this is the approach you should take when using Docker. Store your DB connection parameters (URL, Username, Password) in environment variables. There is no real need to use an environment file unless you have a ton of environment variables, you could also pass an arbitrary number of "-e" parameters to docker as well. This is closer to how services like amazon's ECS will expect you to pass parameters.

If you're going to write those to a file, make sure that the file is encrypted/encoded somehow - storing database passwords in a file in plaintext is not a great security practice.